# wazuh manager - wazuh-db won't start

Tags: ossec, wazuh

I am running Wazuh 4.1.5 and installing only the Wazuh manager on a Debian 10 box.  Starting Wazuh leads to the error message

```
 wazuh-db did not start correctly
```

And that is it.  Is there a debug mode for the logging?
My client is using Wazuh manager in "standalone" mode and using rsyslog to forward the logs.  No agents are installed.

I've run xmllint on ossec.conf and it comes back as valid xml.  I'm at a loss as to where to go next.  TIA for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can activate wazuh_db debug mode adding to */var/ossec/etc/local_internal_options.conf* the following line

```
wazuh_db.debug=2
```

Then, restart wazuh-manager

```
systemctl restart wazuh-manager
```

After that, share with us the ossec.log file in order to troubleshoot this issue.